# GC overhead limit exceeded - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Android studio 2.2 was working good for me and build fast but now after updating to 2.3 ! it takes a lot of time to build my projects and also After a period of time Android studio failed because of this exception

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>   GC overhead limit exceeded

any help !

Answer (score 11):

Try adding this to your `gradle.properties`:

```
        org.gradle.daemon=true
        org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
        org.gradle.parallel=true
        org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

Comment: It would be great if someone would explain what's in a project that makes GC exceed this limit.

Answer (score 0):

I had several problems with tests stuck while migrating to Gradle 5. Some reports went from

```
GC overhead limit exceeded
```

to tests even being deadlocked. What solved my problem, apart from increasing 1g heap to 8g with

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx8g -XX\
  \:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Dfile\
  .encoding=UTF-8
```

was to disable binary resources for [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/blog/2018/10/25/robolectric-4-0/)

```
android.enableUnitTestBinaryResources=false
```

since my project would not support it. Those lines should be settle under `gradle.properties` file.

I also suggest to `invalidate caches & restart` Android Studio, clean project, etc, after setting those configs and before running your gradle tasks again.